# Is p->next->prev the same as p?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am doing a Linked List implementation for my Uni, and i came across this code on our presentations.

```
template <class X> bool linkedList<X>::deleteElement(node<X> *p)
if (p=NULL)
    return false;
if(p->next!=NULL)
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
if(p->prev!=NULL)
    p->prev->next = p->next;
else
    head = p->next
```

I was wondering if the `p->next->prev = p->prev;` part is the same as saying `p = p->prev;` because the previous of the next of p, is p itself.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

EDIT 1: Fixed a typo and added a bit more code to make this more clear.

Comment: The code will crash spectacularly. If `p->next` is `NULL`, then `p->next->prev` will give you a null pointer exception. The code is meaningless. There must be typos.

Comment: it is always easier to work with pointers if you draw a picture of boxes and arrows.  Always helped me.

Comment: @Hogan I've been programming in languages with linked lists for 35 years. I still sometimes need to draw those diagrams (I did it earlier this week while answering another question). :)

Comment: @Barmar Some say "There is no problem in computer science that can't be solved using another level of indirection"   I think it is clearer to say "There is no problem that can't be solved using another box and arrow."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was wondering if the `p->next->prev = p->prev;` part is the same as saying `p = p->prev`

No, it is not.  It is setting the `prev` field of the `next` node that follows the `p` node in the list.

The code is removing the  `p` node from the list.  The *two* surrounding nodes on either side of the `p` node need to be updated to stop pointing at the `p` node and instead point at each other.  What you showed is only half of the necessary update. You need to add the other half: `if (p->prev != NULL) p->prev->next = p->next;`.  You also need to check if `p` points at the head node of the list, and if so then update the head to point at `p->next` instead.  Likewise with the list's tail node, if any, to point at `p->prev`.

Also, the `if(p=NULL)` in your code is wrong, it should be `if(p==NULL)` instead. And the `if(p->next==NULL)` in your code is also wrong, it should be `if(p->next!=NULL)` instead.

Here is the correct implementation:

```
template <class X> bool linkedList<X>::deleteElement(node<X> *p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return false;
    if (p->next != NULL)
        p->next->prev = p->prev;
    if (p->prev != NULL)
        p->prev->next = p->next;
    if (p == head)
        head = p->next;

    // if your list has a tail:
    if (p == tail)
        tail = p->prev;

    // if your list owns the memory for the nodes:
    delete p; // or however you free it

    return true;
}
```

And lastly, you should consider using the STL [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead of a manual implementation.

Comment: Ahh your explanation makes perfect sense.
My mind got stuck for quite some time but you made it clear to me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, basically you want to destroy all evidence that *p* existed. And you can't do that by only modifying p's own variables. So you need to modify its predecessor's `next` and successor's `prev` pointers.  By the way, implementing your own linked list from scratch is a very good exercise forcing you to think about these things before implementing them.

Comment: At Remy and @potAito, i am doing the implementation myself for practice.
It's true that is keeps you on your feet to look for those details(or i see them as details, due to my unfamiliarity).

Answer (score 9):

Not quite. `p` is a local variable. `p->next->prev` is an instance variable on `p->next`. Changing the former won't affect the structure at all, while changing the latter will. To put it another way, their **values** may be the same, but the **memory addresses** where those values are stored are different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. As for the question,  I think the arrow notation got me confused.